# Memory consumed by a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-management

I need to monitor the amount of memory consumed by threads spawned by my application. The idea is to take corrective actions, if a greedy thread consumes too much of memory. I have referred to [How much memory does my java thread take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619211/how-much-memory-does-my-java-thread-take). One of the suggestions on that link is to use `getThreadAllocatedBytes` in `ThreadMXBean.`I experimented with `getThreadAllocatedBytes` with the following job.

```
List<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();
long i = 0;
while (true) {
            primes.add(++i);
            if ((i % 10) == 0) {
                primes.clear();
                System.runFinalization();
                System.gc();
            }
        }
```

I run this job on four threads for considerable time. Though the job does not accumulate memory continuously, the values returned by `getThreadAllocatedBytes` keeps increasing and does not go down even once. This implies that `getThreadAllocatedBytes` does not return the actual amount of memory on heap used by the thread. It returns the total amount of memory allocated on the heap for the thread since it was started. My platform details are as follows:

*Linux PG85213.egi.ericsson.com 3.5.0-030500-generic #201207211835 SMP Sat Jul 21 22:35:55 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "1.7.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)*

Is the above behavior desired behavior of `getThreadAllocatedBytes`?
If so, is there no way to find effective memory on heap used by a thread.

Am listing the complete program for reference:

```
package workbench;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AnotherWorkBench {

private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);
static final List<Long> threadIds = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Long>());

private void dummyJob() {
    List<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long i = 0;
    while (true) {
        primes.add(++i);
        if ((i % 10) == 0) {
            primes.clear();
            //introduce sleep to prevent process hogging 
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AnotherWorkBench.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.runFinalization();
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}

private void runDummyJobs() {

    Runnable dummyJob = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            threadIds.add(Thread.currentThread().getId());
            latch.countDown();
            dummyJob();
        }
    };

    Runnable memoryMonitorJob = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Monitor thread started");
            ThreadMXBean threadMxBean = (ThreadMXBean) ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
            threadMxBean.setThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled(true);

            while (true) {
                for (Long threadId : threadIds) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Thread ID : " + threadId + " : memory = " + threadMxBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(threadId) + " bytes");
                }

                //wait between subsequent scans
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : secondary sleep");
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : out of secondary sleep");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WorkBench.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }


        }
    };

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(dummyJob);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(dummyJob);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(dummyJob);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(dummyJob);

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnotherWorkBench.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(memoryMonitorJob);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AnotherWorkBench().runDummyJobs();
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `System.gc()` does *not* guarantee that the GC is run. Especially in your case, where `System.gc()` is probably called with sub-millisecond intervals, the VM may decide to defer the GC run to some arbitrary time; usually to when available memory becomes low by some measure.

Comment: Could you include a more complete example please, I would like to repeat your experiment locally.

Comment: The SAP JVM (https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud) seems to support exactly this feature. I never used this VM, and only read that it is supported, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no reliable way to do this at runtime.  And as pointed out in  the [source question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619211/how-much-memory-does-my-java-thread-take), the heap is a shared resource and thus the heap size of a single thread does not make sense as it will overlap with objects references from other threads.

That said, when I do want to know the ['retained' size](http://yourkit.com/docs/java/help/sizes.jsp) of a single thread, and yes retained size is a different but similar metric to the one that you asked for, then I do it by taking a heap dump and then using MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

I have known people to use [Java Agents to instrument the allocation of objects](http://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/) and then to use a weak reference to monitor when it gets GC'd.  However the performance impact of doing this is high.  Very high.

You may be best off using a heuristic at runtime and [unit testing to ensure that memory stays within bounds](http://chriskirk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/a-neat-tool-for-detecting-memory-leaks.html).  For example, you could use JMX to monitor the heap sizes and when you see the old gen growing then you can raise an alert.  Using getThreadAllocatedBytes to calculate rate of allocation could also be useful.

Good run time monitoring tools:  [appdynamics](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.appdynamics.com%2F&ei=RcTYU7jNFfOO7QaZvoHQAQ&usg=AFQjCNEok4JU-HIMZA6g-29PHiR6XoFY8w&sig2=2tmZMSm4qsbj3kLD2m4FUQ&bvm=bv.71778758,d.ZGU), [newrelic](http://newrelic.com), [visualvm](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvisualvm.java.net%2F&ei=g8TYU7HNL4vA7AaZxIDYCw&usg=AFQjCNFBQZQEcmC_or0MLSPT9B6TOaAg2Q&sig2=ZqxJ-yLIHaYzAVhm1vuceA&bvm=bv.71778758,d.ZGU) and [yourkit](http://yourkit.com)

For offline memory analysis, [mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and [jclarity](http://www.jclarity.com/) are very good.

A very useful tool to help one spot whether there is a leak, or at least is running different to expectations is to print a count of how many instances of each class are currently on the heap:  [jcmd <pid> GC.class_histogram](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jcmd.html#CIHEEDIB).

Comment: Am primarily interested in run-time monitoring from with in application context. So, profiling application externally will not be of much help in our case. However, I wanted to check whether heap-memory consumption per thread is provided by profilers. All but visualVM were commercially licensed. So I checked VisualVM only. It does not give the amount of heap memory used by each thread. Am not sure whether any other profiler provides this. Based on the replies and all search done so far, there seems no way to get amount of heap-memory consumed per thread.

Comment: @SarveswaranMeenakshiSundaram that is correct, there is no established way to do it.  And as pointed out by some of the replies, what does 'heap-memory consumed per thread' actually mean.  The heap is a shared resource, and any single object can be accessed by multiple threads.  Which is why I mentioned 'retained' size, which is a metric that can be calculated either offline or at runtime.  However at runtime it would cost, and depending on how you did it inaccurate too.  Offline is the normal way to do it, and free tools like MAT support that.  Details of both are above.

Answer (score 4):

[Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) can be used "to monitor a local application and view real-time, high-level data on the memory heap, thread activity, and the classes loaded in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Monitoring an application imposes low overhead and can be used for extended periods."

See also [How to monitor Java memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058991/how-to-monitor-java-memory-usage)
for other possibilities.

Comment: I tried VisualVM. There is a column that displays amount of memory allocated per thread. This matches the values returned by getThreadAllocatedBytes in ThreadMXBean. Even visual VM does not give the actual memory on heap used by each thread! This implies there is no JVM level support/hack to monitor amount of memory used by each thread in real time.

Comment: @gumuruh No idea. This question has nothing to do with Netbeans.