# Measure maximum memory usage of tasks in the task queue of a Java Thread Pool

Tags: java, performance, threadpool

I need to do some performance tests of an application in a remote `AWS` cluster. I've been asked to measure the maximum memory usage of the tasks in the task queue of a Java Thread Pool obtained using `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`.

I know that I can get the number of tasks in the queue using the `Executor` interface, but I don't know how to measure the memory usage of a single task, so I can't calculate the maximum usage.

Comment: You may take a look on [Memory consumed by a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033458/memory-consumed-by-a-thread).

Comment: But don't those tools measure memory usage when a thread is running? I need to know how much memory the tasks consume while they're in the queue, not when they're in the execution pool (i.e.: when they're active).