# Minimum memory allocation for each thread, when JVM reach maximum thread count in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Need to find out that what is the minimum memory allocation for each thread, when JVM reach Maximum Thread count in Java?

Comment: This answers max threads number but not the minimum memory : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763579/how-many-threads-can-a-java-vm-support?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thank you Lutzi. I really appreciate your help, but my main concern is about minimum memory allocation.

Comment: Then this probably answers your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619211/how-much-memory-does-my-java-thread-take

Comment: Minimum memory depends entirely on what the thread would be doing, and we can't answer that. Only you can, by testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 2 MB. A good rule of thumb for maximum thread count is to allow 2MB of ram for each thread.

Comment: You well come Aravinda