# Understanding java memory usage

Tags: java, memory-leaks, gdb, jmap, hprof

I am trying to solve a memory issue I am having with my tomcat servers and I have some questions about memory usage.
When I check my process memory usage with top I see its using 1Gb physical memory, after creating a core dump using gdb, the core file size is 2.5GB , and when analyzing the HPROF file created by jmap , it states that 240MB is used.

So if top shows 1GB why does the hprof file show only 240MB where did 760MB go ?

Comment: Is 240MB shown as Heap memory? If not, what is the Used Heap in it? Can you provide some details on the numbers provided by jmap

Comment: I think so, this is the total size shown in Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Comment: If you only dump live objects this can be a fraction of the heap which is a fraction of the memory the process uses.

Comment: the 'live' option wasnt used in jmap

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Jmap using `-heap:format` option set? JVM usually runs a GC before taking a dump.

Also, [JVM memory](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:JvmSpec7.png) is not just Heap Memory. It contains Code, Stack, Native method, Direct memory, even Threads are not [free to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619211/how-much-memory-does-my-java-thread-take). you could read more about it [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/garbage-collection/jvm-memory-model-structure-and-components/). Just make sure to see if all these also add up to it.

I would suggest using *VisualVM* or *yourkit* and compare the memory. Also, which GC are you using?
 Some GC's don't usually shrink the heap memory after increasing, but if GC got triggered during heapdump it might have freed up some memory(Try **G1GC**).

Comment: the heap dump was created from a core dump file ( created by gdb ) doesnt this mean that there was no GC before heap dump ?